# Deleting an empty line in Python

Tags: python, text, lines

I have the text file:

```
ACQUIRED  
ALMANAC  
INSULT  
JOKE  
HYMN   
GAZELLE  
AMAZON  
EYEBROWS  
AFFIX  
VELLUM
```

Unfortunately there is an empty (blank) line under the word `VELLUM`. I am wondering how do I delete this line in Python and not just simply deleting it from notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if a line is only whitespace pretty easily:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   line = line.strip()
   if line:
      print line
```

lines that are only whitespace will be empty after the call to [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("A.txt") as inf, open("B.txt", "w") as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if line.strip():
            outf.write(line)
```

copies only non-blank lines to a new text file.